# Do we simplify the Proof by Contradiction?

Tags: functions

Prove the following by contradiction:

Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $4|\left(a^2+b^2\right)$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd (in other words, $a$ and $b$ are even)

So, I did this:

> Assume $a$ and $b$ are odd
>   
>   Let $a={2k+1}$
>   
>   Let $b={2l+1}$
>   
>   
>   $4|\left((2k+1\right)^2+\left(2l+1\right))^2$
>   
>   $\left(2k+1\right)*\left(2k+1\right)=4k^2+4k+1$
>   
>   $\left(2l+1\right)*\left(2l+1\right)=4l^2+4l+1$
>   
>   
>   $4|\left(\left(4k^2+4k+1\right)+\left(4l^2+4l+1\right)\right)$
>   
>   
>   For this, do we still, simplify it
>   
>   Or, what do you do after that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(2k + 1)^2 + (2l + 1)^2 = 4\left(k^2 + l^2 + k + l\right) + 2
$$

This means that $\left(a^2 + b^2\right) = 4 \lambda + 2$, meaning that $4$ could not possibly divide $\left(a^2 + b^2\right)$, since there's always a remainder of $2$.

...by the way, this means that for $4$ to divide $a^2 + b^2$, both $a$ and $b$ must be even, since certainly if one is odd and the other even, you will get an odd.  Further, if they are *both* even, then $4$ *definitely* divides them.

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks

So, that is correct, or nearly correct?

Comment: Thanks, @Jared
<br/>

For the help

Answer (score 0):

Because 
$$
a^2+b^2=(a-b)^2+2ab,
$$
if $a^2+b^2$ is even, then $a$ and $b$ must share parity. But if $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then $(a-b)^2$ is divisible by $4$ whereas $2ab$ is not, so it must be that $a$ and $b$ are both even.

Comment: Thanks, @Kim Jong Un
<br/>
That really helps

Thanks so much